# Both Sin[x]==0 && Cos[x]==0 as a solution

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

If I do

```
FullSimplify[Reduce[Sin[p1] == 0 && Cos[p1] == 0, Reals]]
```

I get

```
 Cos[p1] == 0 && Sin[p1] == 0
```

while I would expect False. why?
is there a way to have mathematica compute that both sin and cos cannot be 0?

Comment: `Reduce[Sin[p1] == 0 && Cos[p1] == 0, p1]` returns the expected result.

Comment: Domain specification `Reals` is unnecessary.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: Thank you @J.M., If you write it as an answer I will mark it as definitive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted, specifying the variable of interest within `Reduce[]` yields the expected result:

```
Reduce[Sin[p1] == 0 && Cos[p1] == 0, p1]
   False
```